# How to make a input field require depending in a condition?

Tags: angular

I have an input field that I want to show or hide, that depends if the user selected a certain option from the fields before this.
So I need that when this field is hidden, to clear/remove /or not making the field required. I have shown both fields that I am using, please if anyone has any idea, it would  really help me !!

```
    <mat-form-field formGroupName="industry">
        <mat-select formControlName="id" placeholder="Industry" (selectionChange)="changed($event)">
          <mat-option>None</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of industries" [value]="item.id">
            {{item.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>

        <div
          *ngIf="industryForm.controls.id.invalid && (industryForm.controls.id.dirty || industryForm.controls.id.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <mat-error *ngIf="industryForm.controls.id.errors.required">Must fill this field</mat-error>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper" *ngIf="show">
    <div class="question-wrapper">
      <h3 class="mat-subheading-1">
        Other Industry
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [required]="show"
          placeholder="Other Industry (min 1 to max 50 characters)"
          formControlName="otherIndustry"
          maxlength="50"
          id="otherTypeOfSoftware"/>

        <div *ngIf="f.otherIndustry.invalid && (f.otherIndustry.dirty || f.otherIndustry.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <mat-error *ngIf="f.otherIndustry.errors.required">Must fill this field</mat-error>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the typescript code that I trying to show/hide the field :

```
   changed(e) {
  this.form.controls.industry.setValue(this.selectedIndustry);

  if (this.selectedIndustry = 13) {
    this.show = true;
  } else {
    this.show = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will do the job and provide required as default in your form definition.

```
changed(e) {
         this.form.controls.industry.setValue(this.selectedIndustry);
         if (this.selectedIndustry = 13) {
          this.form.get('otherIndustry').enable();
         } else {
          this.form.get('otherIndustry').disable();
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hide them, call the `disable()` method on the hidden form controls and their validation state will not affect the validation state of the form group.  And when you show them, call `enable()` on the form controls that have become visible.